# Spring Boot - Method being called ridicolously multiple times

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

Well, I don't know if this is a problem about the method or about logging, but in production, the log is being filled with the same line within a small amount of milliseconds.

Here's a piece of my log:

```
2018-09-19 15:23:36.070  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-105] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.117  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-101] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.150  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-104] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.192  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-96] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.224  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-86] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.266  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-92] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.298  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-107] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.339  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-80] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.372  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-89] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.414  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-84] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.447  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-105] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.487  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-101] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.519  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-104] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.559  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-96] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.590  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-86] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.638  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-92] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.670  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-107] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.711  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-80] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.743  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-89] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.784  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-84] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.815  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-105] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.856  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-101] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.887  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-104] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.928  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-96] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:36.961  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-86] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
2018-09-19 15:23:37.002  INFO 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-92] c.d.b.o.s.i.UserServiceImpl    : Getting user - User(id=34, status=VALID, firstname=John, lastname=Doe)
```

Any clue on this?

Comment: Multiple requests coming in from the same user. Each `script`, `img`, `link` etc. will result in a call to the server. Each of them will pass through the filters etc. and probably you need to login with each request.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is a service method. It has nothing to do with a filter.

Comment: This is a `UserServiceImpl` which is probably used in your login/authentication/... which is generally a filter (or whatever you use). Regardless the result is coming from multiple request from things retrieved from your web page.

Comment: @M.Deinum no this method is not being used for login purposes. I don't know if is coming from multiple requests. How can differents users in differents moments, and with so little time between each request be doing this? It's look like another thing, but I have no clue...

Comment: It isn't... I suggest a read on how the web works and how html is parsed and processed on the browser. It is coming from multiple requests because the thread is clearly from the request handling pool and differs. So it are multiple requests. Something in your flow of downloading resources is triggering the user from being retrieved. Nonetheless why should that be a problem at all?